# Does a clicked on item go out of scope when going into the getJSON section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, web

When clicking on a list item, does it go out of scope when going into the `getJSON` section where I want to go and get data from a database?

I have a list of items displaying colours. Each list item has an ID set to that of a SKU. When I click on a list item, it must go and get data from the database for that SKU and populate the contents on the page.

I was playing around with some code and for interest's sake I wanted to see if I could change the text of the clicked on list item. So after the JSON call is done, I tried to set the text, but nothing happened.

I get the sku of the clicked on list item like this:

```
var sku = this.id;
```

After I do the JSON call I tried to set the text of this clicked on list item like this:

```
this.text('sample text');
```

I even tried:

```
this.Text('sample text');
```

Here is my full JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.attributes li').click(function () {
               var url = 'www.example.com/test-url';
               var sku = this.id;
               $.getJSON(url, { sku: sku }, function (data) {
                    // This does not work
                    this.Text('sample text');
               });
          });
     });
</script>
```

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<ul class="list-inline attributes selectable">
     <li id="sku0001">Blue</li>
     <li id="sku0002">Green</li>
     <li id="sku0003">Red</li>
     <li id="sku0004">Yellow</li>
</ul>
```

When going into the `getJSON` section does the `this` go out of focus? Does the clicked on list item go out of scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!! When it gets into `.getJSON`, `this` will loose its context and `this` will refer to callback function of `$.getJSON` and will no more be referring to `li`. I would suggest to create an instance of `this` outside `$.getJSON` like `var that=this` and then assign `that.text` inside `$.getJSON`

**Example:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.attributes li').click(function () {
           var that=this;
           var url = 'www.example.com/test-url';
           var sku = this.id;
           $.getJSON(url, { sku: sku }, function (data) {
                 // this here does not work because it refers to callback function
                 that.text('sample text'); //assign with that referred previously
           });
      });
});
```

Alternatively, if you are using `ajax` you add an extra option called `context` to refer `this` anywhere inside the `ajax`

```
$('.attributes li').click(function () {
    var url = 'www.example.com/test-url';
    var sku = this.id;
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        dataType : 'json',
        data:{sku:sku},
        context : this, //add this
        complete : function (data) {
            // 'this' will be what you passed as context 
            $(this).text('sample text')
        }
    });
});
```